# Replace a pattern-matching field with field's value from previous row

Tags: awk, replace, pattern-matching, field

maybe the title is not a good description but, essentially, this is the problem I am trying to solve:

- I have a text file with *n* rows and *m* space-separater fields in each row
- if field *j* of row *i* matches a pattern, replace it with field *j* from row *i* - 1

I am not forced to use AWK (GAWK in this instance), but it seemed a good choice for this operation. This is the sript I wrote and it work as expected, but I was wondering if there is a more time-efficient way to solve the problem

```
{
    if ($0!~/NoData/) {
        split($0, data, " ");
        print $0
    } else {
        split($0, row, " ", seps);
        for(i in row) {if (row[i]~/NoData/) row[i]=data[i]; else data[i]=row[i]; printf "%s%s", row[i], seps[i];}
        printf "\n"                                                                                                                                               
    }
}
```

As a sample, the script, running on this input file

```
0.8147    0.2785    0.9572    0.7922    0.6787    0.7060
0.9058    0.5469    0.4854    0.9595    0.7577    0.0318
0.1270    0.9575    0.8003    0.6557    0.7431    0.2769
0.9134    0.9649    NoData    0.0357    0.3922    0.0462
0.6324    0.1576    NoData    NoData    0.6555    0.0971
0.0975    0.9706    NoData    NoData    0.1712    0.8235
```

should produce this result

```
0.8147    0.2785    0.9572    0.7922    0.6787    0.7060
0.9058    0.5469    0.4854    0.9595    0.7577    0.0318
0.1270    0.9575    0.8003    0.6557    0.7431    0.2769
0.9134    0.9649    0.8003    0.0357    0.3922    0.0462
0.6324    0.1576    0.8003    0.0357    0.6555    0.0971
0.0975    0.9706    0.8003    0.0357    0.1712    0.8235
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i~/NoData/){ $i=last[i]; } last[i]=$i }  }1' file
```

If you want to preserve original formatting, you may use below, if you have `gawk` 4th argument for `split` may be utilized.

```
awk '{
       split($0,D,/[^[:space:]]*/);
       s = "";
       for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ 
            if($i~/NoData/){ $i =  last[i]; } 
            last[i]=$i ; 
            s = s  sprintf("%s%s",D[i],$i) 
       }  
       print s
 }' file
```

OR by setting `OFS=""` or `OFS=`

```
awk -v OFS= '{
       split($0,D,/[^[:space:]]*/);
       for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ 
            if($i~/NoData/){ $i =  last[i]; } 
            last[i]=$i ; 
            $i = sprintf("%s%s",D[i],$i) 
       }  
 }1' file
```

**Example - 1 ( Preserve Formatting )**

```
$ cat file
0.8147    0.2785    0.9572    0.7922    0.6787    0.7060
0.9058    0.5469    0.4854    0.9595    0.7577    0.0318
0.1270    0.9575    0.8003    0.6557    0.7431    0.2769
0.9134    0.9649    NoData    0.0357    0.3922    0.0462
0.6324    0.1576    NoData    NoData    0.6555    0.0971
0.0975    0.9706    NoData    NoData    0.1712    0.8235

$ awk '{
       split($0,D,/[^[:space:]]*/);
       s = "";
       for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ 
            if($i~/NoData/){ $i =  last[i]; } 
            last[i]=$i ; 
            s = s  sprintf("%s%s",D[i],$i) 
       }  
       print s
 }' file
0.8147    0.2785    0.9572    0.7922    0.6787    0.7060
0.9058    0.5469    0.4854    0.9595    0.7577    0.0318
0.1270    0.9575    0.8003    0.6557    0.7431    0.2769
0.9134    0.9649    0.8003    0.0357    0.3922    0.0462
0.6324    0.1576    0.8003    0.0357    0.6555    0.0971
0.0975    0.9706    0.8003    0.0357    0.1712    0.8235
```

**Example - 2 ( Without Preserving Source Formatting )**

It takes single space as output separator by default, in case if you set `OFS` it will override default value.

```
$ cat file
0.8147    0.2785    0.9572    0.7922    0.6787    0.7060
0.9058    0.5469    0.4854    0.9595    0.7577    0.0318
0.1270    0.9575    0.8003    0.6557    0.7431    0.2769
0.9134    0.9649    NoData    0.0357    0.3922    0.0462
0.6324    0.1576    NoData    NoData    0.6555    0.0971
0.0975    0.9706    NoData    NoData    0.1712    0.8235

$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i~/NoData/){ $i=last[i]; } last[i]=$i }  }1' file
0.8147    0.2785    0.9572    0.7922    0.6787    0.7060
0.9058    0.5469    0.4854    0.9595    0.7577    0.0318
0.1270    0.9575    0.8003    0.6557    0.7431    0.2769
0.9134 0.9649 0.8003 0.0357 0.3922 0.0462
0.6324 0.1576 0.8003 0.0357 0.6555 0.0971
0.0975 0.9706 0.8003 0.0357 0.1712 0.8235
```

Comment: Wow, quick and short. What does that 1 at the end do?

Comment: @Patrik `1` does default operation `print $0` (print current line/record/row)  meaning its true can be any nonzero number

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think preserving the formatting is not a priority because the output will be parsed by other programs. It is fine, as long as there is at least one space

Comment: @Patrik: Ok, then no problem, but to meet the expected o/p I gave other solution along with.